# How to add an attachment to an email using VB.net

Tags: vb.net

I don't know how to add an attachment to my email that will be sent out when the user presses the send request button. The attachment is just a PDF file. I have tried multiple things but none seem to work.

Here's the code I'm using to create the mail message:

```
Dim _strStyle As String = Nothing
Dim _objMSG As New System.Net.Mail.MailMessage()
Dim _FromAddress As New System.Net.Mail.MailAddress("fakeemail@fake.com")

_strStyle += "<style>"
_strStyle += ".css_bubbles__EMP_home"
_strStyle += "{      "
_strStyle += "float:left;"
_strStyle += "margin:10px 10px 10px 10px;"
_strStyle += "padding:10px 10px 10px 10px;"
_strStyle += "border-top-left-radius:15px;"
_strStyle += "border-top-right-radius:15px;"
_strStyle += "border-bottom-left-radius:15px;"
_strStyle += "border-bottom-right-radius:15px;"
_strStyle += "background-color:#ffffff;"
_strStyle += "border: solid;"
_strStyle += "border-width:2px;"
_strStyle += "border-color:#7FAA01;"
_strStyle += "}"
_strStyle += "</style>"

_objMSG.IsBodyHtml = True
_objMSG.Subject = "RE: You have been invited to attend a meeting."
_objMSG.From = _FromAddress
_objMSG.To.Add(txb_Email.Text)

_objMSG.Body += "<html><head>"
_objMSG.Body += _strStyle
_objMSG.Body += "</head><body>"
_objMSG.Body += "<div class='css_bubbles__EMP_home'>"
_objMSG.Body += "You have a new enquiry:"
_objMSG.Body += "<br /><br />"

_objMSG.Body += "Name: "
_objMSG.Body += Me.txb_Name.Text
_objMSG.Body += "<br /><br />"

_objMSG.Body += "Email Address: "
_objMSG.Body += Me.txb_Email.Text
_objMSG.Body += "<br /><br />"

_objMSG.Body += "Telephone Number: "
_objMSG.Body += Me.txb_Telephone.Text
_objMSG.Body += "<br /><br />"

_objMSG.Body += "Postcode: "
_objMSG.Body += Me.txb_Postcode.Text
_objMSG.Body += "<br /><br />"

_objMSG.Body += "First Line of Address: "
_objMSG.Body += Me.txb_Address.Text
_objMSG.Body += "<br /><br />"

_objMSG.Body += "City/Town: "
_objMSG.Body += Me.txb_City.Text
_objMSG.Body += "<br /><br />"

_objMSG.Body += "</div>"
_objMSG.Body += "</body></html>"
_objMSG.Body += "<br /><br />"
```

And here is the code that I'm using to send the message:

```
Private Sub Send(ByVal p_objMSG As System.Net.Mail.MailMessage)
    Dim _objCredentials As New System.Net.NetworkCredential
    _objCredentials.UserName = "fakename"
    _objCredentials.Password = "fakepassword"

    Dim _objSMTPCLIENT As New System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient("smtp.sendgrid.net", 25)
    _objSMTPCLIENT.Credentials = _objCredentials
    _objSMTPCLIENT.Host = "smtp.sendgrid.net"
    _objSMTPCLIENT.Send(p_objMSG)
End Sub
```

Comment: There is a simple example in the [Attachments property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.mailmessage.attachments(v=vs.110).aspx) of MailMessage. I presume that the first thing to do when you search something NET related shoud be going to MSDN.

Comment: In the future, rather than just saying that you tried stuff that didn't work, it would be better if you explained what you tried and how it didn't work.  I cleaned up your example code so that it only includes the pertinent parts, but it's still overly long.  It's always best to keep your example code as concise as possible.  The shorter it is, the more willing people will be to read it.  Obviously it needs to be long enough to demonstrate the issue, but, in this case, the body of the email could probably just be "Hello world" and the example would still demonstrate your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way I can think of would be something like this...

```
Dim filePath as String
Dim attach As New Net.Mail.Attachment(filePath)
mailMsg.Attachments.Add(attach)
```